# which iframe has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I may be missing something here, but I want to have something similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/Kxmaf/6/ but with several iframe areas to be edited. How do I determine which Iframe has focus on it?

What I want to be able to do is enter something like this:

```
function ItalicIt()
 {  
    var edit = document.activeElement;
    edit.focus();
    edit.document.execCommand("italic", false, "");
    edit.focus();
 }
```

instead of this:

```
function ItalicIt()
 {  
    var edit = document.getElementById("textEditor").contentWindow;
    edit.focus();
    edit.document.execCommand("italic", false, "");
    edit.focus();
 }
```

So, instead of telling it which iframe to act on by giving it the id "texteditor," I want to tell it to figure out which one has the focus.